# RBAC in ASP.NET using Identity system

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, rbac, duende-identity-server, duende

I am using ASP.NET Identity with Identity Server to build an authentication system, and I want to assign each role a set of permissions. However, I am confused about how to store these permissions correctly.

I try to store them as claims for the role but I'm not very happy with this solution.

Comment: What do you mean identity server? Are you using 'identity server 4' or something like that? or just built in usermanager with database.

Comment: sorry i mean duende identity server

Comment: first of all, is there a specific reason you are using duende? why not just use identity itself? anyway, perhaps your answer is in the official duende documentation https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/quickstarts/5_aspnetid/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.